# colorbox css problem in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, colorbox

i have a strange problem only in IE when i initialize the colorbox ....
can anyone hintout how to fix it?

in mozilla and chrome all is ok

to see it just search for an agent in any country and select any option from 3 demo values

Comment: What's the problem that you see, exactly?

Comment: @Blender there is no bottom and right borders of colorbox   here is a screenshot http://floomby.ru/content/lFOTyCiik6/

Comment: Your page is in "quirks" mode - you really should get it into standards-compliant mode first or all sorts of things are going to be messed up.

Comment: There's a lot of different errors in your IE page...  No borders, no overlay, and some other random things just seem to be formatting wrong.  I'd listen to Pointy and switch to standards-compliant mode..  Makes debugging much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your widths are showing up different in IE for some reason, which is causing them to be cut off.

To fix this, you need to allow overflowing content on your colorbox div.  You can either do it in CSS or JQuery.

### CSS

```
#colorbox {
     overflow: visible;
}
```

### JQuery

```
$("#colorbox").css('overflow', 'visible');
```

---

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

**CSS**

```
#colorbox {
     overflow: visible!important;
}
```